# PyQt5 - Scroll to QTextEdit's cursor

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5

I'm developping a text editor with PyQt5 and I'm implementing "Find next..." function.  The user enters the string that he wants to search for. Every time he clicks on the "Find next" button, the next matching string will be highlighted.
[image: Like this]

I've done that using QTextEdit.textCursor() like this:

```
...
textarea = QTextEdit()
cursor = textarea.textCursor()

#This function returns an array: [start index of the matched string, end index of the matched string]
matched_string_indexes = findText(text_to_find, text,...) 

#So now I can use setPosition to select the matched string
cursor.setPosition(array[0], QTextEdit.MoveAnchor)
cursor.setPosition(array[1], QTextEdit.KeepAnchor)

#Now that the matched string is seleted I can highlight it
highlightText(cursor)
```

The problem is if the matching string is at the bottom of the page (out of the view port), I want the textarea to scroll down(or up) automatically. I tried with QTextEdit's ensureCursorVisible() method but it doesn't work.

A brute-force solution is to calculate the current line's y coordiate in pixel than use scrollbar.setValue() method to scroll to that line.

Comment: Surely you will have to call `textarea.setTextCursor(cursor)` in order for `ensureCursorVisible()` to work.

Comment: It worked omg... I was so sure that the cursor returned by QTextEdit.textCursor() method must be "set" as the textarea's cursor. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, I just have to to:

```
textarea.ensureCursorVisible()
#AND
textare.setTextCursor(cursor)
```

The QTextEdit's textCursor() method returns a COPY of its cursor, not the real one so we have to set it with setTextCursor() method.

Comment: I spend 3 hour to find this solution. thanks it works fine!